# How to Add a Constraint on the Derivative of the Model in FindFit

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I would like to add constraints on a model and its derivatives and then use `FindFit` to fit some parameters. An example is below:

```
modelt[a_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ] := (modelt[a, k] = 
First[x /.NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1/2)*y[t]*(Sin[x[t] + a] + Cos[x[t] + a]), 
y'[t] == k Sin[x[t]], x[0] == Pi/2, y[0] == 1/2}, {x,  y}, {t, 0, 1000}]])

FindFit[{1000, Pi/6}, {modelt[a, k][t]}, {a, k}, t, 
 Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"}]
```

Is there a way to add constraints to `FindFit` such as `x'[1000] == 0, x''[1000] < 0,`. How do you go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Formally, you can add additional constraints to second argument of `FindFit` (see help). And because `x[t]` is `modelt[a, k][t]` you can write smth. like `FindFit[{1000, Pi/6}, {modelt[a, k][t], modelt[a, k]'[1000]==0,modelt[a, k]''[1000]<0}, {a, k}, t, Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"}]`.

Comment: Hey @Alx ! Thanks for the help, you were correct in your suggestion! I will add it as a solution.

Comment: @Alx, I have started working on combining your solution with another popular question on FindFit but have come to a bit of a roadblock, if you have a second let me know! Here is the link to it:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208054/selecting-specific-elements-of-a-model-in-findfit-for-constraints

Answer (score 1):

As @Alx suggested in the comments, adding constraints onto the model such as `modelt[a, k]'[1000]==0,modelt[a, k]''[1000]<0` was the correct method. Thanks to him!